# Concatenate Files with a certain word?

Tags: cat

I've been using the `cat` command to concatenate files. To expedite the process is there a way to `cat` files that have a certain word in middle of the file name. I know how to use the asterisk to capture a certain word in the beginning or the end but not the middle.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
cat *word* > new_file
```

Now all the files with the "word" in their name will be concatenated in "new_file".